# How to access request data in flask request

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, post

I am trying to access my POST method written in python through javascript and ajax. Below is the javascript code.

```
       $('#aht_btn').click(function(){

 var input1 = $("#data").val();
    alert("input.."+input1);    
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:5000/train",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: input1,
    success: function (data) {
    alert(data);

    },
    error: function (error) {
    alert(error);
       // $('.messages').html(error);
    }
});
```

My python POST method is as below.

```
@app.route('/train',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def train_system():
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5,
                                stop_words='english')

features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = 
TwitterProcess.preprocess()

#logreg=LogisticRegression()
tLogReg=time()
Twitter.logreg.fit(features_train, labels_train)
print "training time for Logistic Regression:", round(time()-tLogReg, 3), 
"s"
t2 = time()
pred = Twitter.logreg.predict(features_test)

while True:
    #flag=raw_input("Do you want to classify the data?(Y/N)")
    print "Enter classification"

    print request.json

    flag = request.get_json()

    print flag
```

When I am printing this "flag" its printing None.

How  i can receive the request data sent through Ajax call in my Python post method..

Answer (score 1):

try something like below.. you have to add 'contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' '

```
$('#aht_btn').click(function(){
    var input1 = $("#data").val();
    alert("input.." + input1);   
    request_data = { input1 } 
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:5000/train",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',//missing this
        data: JSON.stringify(request_data),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: When I am adding contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', my post method is not getting called.

Comment: check your console.. network. and let me know the error

Comment: I checked in Network.. when adding contentType, Method is coming as OPTION. without contentType Method is POST and going correctly inside my function.